# Export CSV/XLS from Meteor application

Tags: csv, meteor, npm, export-to-csv, iron-router

What is the simplest way to export data to CSV from Meteor?
How to generate CSV?

### What I've tried

Add Npm package:

```
$ meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

Add Node.js CSV suite:

```
// packages.json

{
  "csv": "0.4.0",
}
```

Add Iron Router package:

```
$ meteor add iron:router
```

Configure router on `server`:

```
// server/router.coffee

Router.map ->
  @route 'exportCSV',
    where: 'server'
    path: '/export-csv/:id'
    onAfterAction: ->
      data = ... // Generated CSV 
      filename = 'filename.csv'
      headers =
        'Content-type': 'text/csv'
        'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + filename
      @response.writeHead 200, headers
      @response.end file
```

Answer (score 2):

For my use-case, all of the data was already published to the client. So I decided to generate the file there, using [FileSaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/).

Here's a basic class to build a csv by calling `addRow()`, then call `download('xxx.csv')` to have the user download the file.

```
class CsvBuilder

  constructor: ->
    @content = []

  line: ->
    row = [].slice.call(arguments)
    if row.length  == 0
      @addBlankRow()
    else
      @addRow(row)
    return

  addRow: (row)->
    @content.push(@row2Csv(row), "\n")
    return

  addBlankRow: ->
    @content.push("", "\n")
    return

  row2Csv: (row)->
    d = ''
    for cell in row
      d += '"' + (cell + "").replace(/"/g, '""') + '",'
    return d

  download: (filename)->
    try
      isFileSaverSupported = !!new FileSaver.Blob()

    unless isFileSaverSupported
      window.alert("Save as CSV not supported");
      return

    contentBlob = new FileSaver.Blob(@content, {type: "text/csv;charset=utf-8"})
    FileSaver.saveAs(contentBlob, filename)
    return

  destroy: ->
    @content = []
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the FileSave.js from [eligrey/Filesaver](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/) and save in `lib` folder in you client

```
'click .btnRawCSV' : function() {
    var rawData = Gifts.find({
                              receiptdate:{
                                         $gte: Session.get("giftsStartDate"),
                                         $lte: Session.get("giftsEndDate")
                                          }
                                }).fetch();
    csv = json2csv( rawData, true, true );
    var blob = new Blob([csv], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8;",});

    saveAs(blob, "rawgifts.csv");    
},
```